# Multiple installations communicating with each other

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, cmd, communication

I'm looking to develop a program that is installed on two computers, one being a 'server' and one being a 'client'. The client sided software will send commands to the server, basic things like CMD commands etc.

Any idea on how to get the communication starting?

Edit: 
The software will detect if the installation is on a 'client side' or a 'server side' (Through operating systems, 'E.g Windows Server 2008/Windows 7') The user will then be prompted to login (Backed by a database) and the client side of the software will then detect all servers installed and be able to send basic commands to the server side such as and not limited to, 'Shut down'; 'Sleep'; 'Change Password'.

However, I'm having trouble getting the commands sent over from the client side to the server side, I hope this clears up the question.

Both server/client will be connected to each other through a host server or directly.

Comment: This question needs more details to be provided for anyone to even attempt to provide an answer.

Most important detail which is missing is the information regarding how the 2 computers are connected/networked?

Comment: I've cleared up my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are MANY ways to accomplish what you're asking for. Without more specifics, it's difficult to give you a simple answer.

In most modern-day environments, UDP and TCP/IP over Ethernet/WiFi are the primary fundamental networking technologies which most communications technologies use to pass data around.

In Windows, you have a number of options for passing data between two or more machines including:

- UDP message broadcast
- TCP sockets
- RPC - a C-based API that allows a 'client' to call services offered by a 'server'
- DCOM - a COM-based layer over RPC
- COM+ (.NET Enterprise Services) - a more powerful alternative to DCOM
- WCF - A very flexible, extensible programming interface over many combinations of different encodings (i.e. binary, XML, JSON) and transports (i.e. UDP, TCP, named pipes, HTTP) underneath
- Web - passing XML/JSON over HTTP (which itself uses TCP underneath)
- Queueing (MSMQ, MQ-Series, RabbitMQ, etc.) - for buffered-async (potentially disconnected) communications
- And [many, many more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663286(v=vs.85).aspx)!

If you're starting off, you might want to try creating two simple command-line apps which use TCP sockets to pass simple data (e.g. "Hello World") from a 'client' to a 'server' that's listening on a TCP port.

If you want to get a little more sophisticated, you might also want to look at my WCF-based **[Magic8Ball](https://github.com/bitcrazed/Magic8Ball)** sample client and service project.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using the TcpListener class in your server which will listen on a port to accept connections from clients.

The client would then use the TcpClient class to connect to the server's port and uses the TcpClient's stream to output commands to the server.

There are plenty of simple implementations on the internet which can be found by googling "C# TCP server and client".